# APIs for observing changes to files and folders in business Office365?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api, audit-trail

I am looking for an API that would allow me to do the following: given a business subscription for Office365 and Admin level access, I would like to receive events about file and folder changes.

Example events I am interested it:

> Billy uploaded a cat1.jpg to /drives/123/cats on %datetime% 
>   Sally created a file.txt in /drives/123/work_in_progress on %datetime% 
>   Jay shared a data.csv in /drives/123/data with bob@example.com on %datetime%

I've looked at [activities API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/activities_list) and [webhooks subscription](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription) but not sure if these are the right ones for the purpuses.

Can someone please suggest APIs I can use to get such audit trail data from Office365/OneDrive?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scale, [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/using-webhooks) and [Deltas](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta) are excellent candidates for this.

Where you'll likely run into challenges is if you're attempting to centrally audit across an entire organization. These endpoints are scoped to a single user/directory/drive/etc. so they are less than ideal for organization-wide auditing.

For broader/top-level auditing, I would instead look at the [Office 365 Management Activity API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference). This API includes the ability to audit [SharePoint File Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-schema#sharepoint-file-operations).